# linking virtual machine as server and client

Tags: linux, vmware

I have multiple virtual machine(vmware)(linux) but would like to make one as the server, meaning all the client who wants to access the internet, uses the server internet so, the server is able to view all the incoming and outgoing data packets.

Also, I would like to install another virtual machine to act as an IDS to track the server packet, if anything is wrong it is able to flag out.

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Your question is very broad and imprecise. Also, what have you tried so far, where exactly does your problem arise? Please see [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: thanks for the link and info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup one Linux server as the gateway for the others. All you need is to create two virtual ethernet interfaces for it, one in bridged mode and other in virtual network mode.

One will be bridged with your actual network and act as the WAN, and the other will be act as a LAN gateway for others VM's.

So other VM's should use your server virtual network IP address as main gateway, and you can use tcpdump or wireshard or everything you like to sniff traffic forwarded.

One thing you need to configure on the server is IP forwarding option in sysctl, which is disabled by default:

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

You may find more relevant information [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips) too.
Hope it will help you.